# How can I build Flutter appbundle with a locale engine?

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, app-bundle

I've built local engine according to the document https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine

In my out directory, there are 4 directories, which is android_debug_unopt, android_debug_unopt_arm64, host_debug_unopt, host_debug_unopt_arm64

I can build appbundle or apk with a single architecture, for example:

```
flutter build appbundle --debug --local-engine-src-path=/Volumes/Data/engine/src --local-engine=android_debug_unopt --target-platform android-arm
```

It will be executed successfully.

However, I want to build appbunndle or apk with multiply architecture, including arm and arm64, but I build it failed with the command below:

```
flutter build appbundle --debug --local-engine-src-path=/Volumes/Data/engine/src --local-engine=android_debug_unopt_arm,android_debug_unopt_arm64 --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
```

because we cannot give --local-engine argument two paths.

How can I build appbundle or apk with local engine and multiply architecture?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?